# How to get public IP from Ansible azure_rm_publicipaddress_facts module into a variable to use with add_host?

Tags: azure, ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to set up a pipeline for Azure automation with Ansible, all working, except when I try to get the public IP address into a variable to use with add_host.
Here is my example task:

```
---
- name: Get Public IP
  azure_rm_publicipaddress_facts:
    resource_group: '{{ my_resource_group }}'
    name: '{{ my_name }}'
  register: azure_ip

- debug: var=azure_ip verbosity=2

- name: Add new instance to host group
  add_host:
    hostname: '{{ item.ipAddress }}'
    groupname: launched
  with_items: azure_ip.azure_publicipaddresses
```

With this giving me the following error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined.

However the value is there as shown :

```
TASK [azure : debug] ***********************************************************
task path: mytest/roles/azure/tasks/get_ip.yml:14
ok: [localhost] => {
    "azure_ip": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "azure_publicipaddresses": [
                {
                    "etag": “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/0000000000000/resourceGroups/myrgrp/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/my_ip_001",
                    "location": “euwest",
                    "name": “my_ip_001",
                    "properties": {
                        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
                        "ipAddress": “20.113.125.63",
                        "ipConfiguration": {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/000000000000/resourceGroups/mygrprgrp/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/myrgrp-nic001/ipConfigurations/default"
                        },
                        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                        "publicIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
                        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                        "resourceGuid": “fffff-4444444-cccccc"
                    },
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses"
                }
            ]
        },
        "changed": false
    }
}
```

So, I guess I'm missing something, could anybody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
- name: Add new instance to host group
  add_host:
    hostname: '{{ item.ipAddress }}'
    groupname: launched
  with_items: azure_ip.azure_publicipaddresses
```

To:

```
- name: Add new instance to host group
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ item.properties.ipAddress }}"
    groupname: launched
  with_items: "{{ azure_ip.ansible_facts.azure_publicipaddresses }}"
```

- with `with_items` you need to include the variable in `"{{ }}"` since a few Ansible versions
- key names you referenced seem different from the debug output